# How to make a script run only once across OS upgrades

Tags: linux, bash, debian, upgrade

I want my bash script to run only once at its first boot and never again when I **upgrade** the operating system package. I am specifically looking in the upgrade scenario since all root partitions will be replaced with new files.

**EDIT**: The script is located at `/etc/init.d/testscript` with default run levels. I am trying to make it run only once at its first boot based on a dummy file exists or not, as shown below:

```
FILE="/home/firstboot.log"
test -e $FILE || exit 0
...
rm $FILE
```

The catch here is if the file `firstboot.log` is created from the package for example in version v1.0, and when upgrade is performed to same package of version v2.0 the file is created again which makes my script run after upgrade which I want to avoid. May I know how can I do this.

Comment: It might be impossible. Can't you just put your script in a different file system (e.g. `/home/`, or `/usr/local/` mounted *outside* of `/usr/`) and run it when you upgrade the OS. However, some upgrades don't *erase* the root partition

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Please check my edit in the question.

Comment: What is your script actually doing, and why should you do something specific on distro upgrades? I am not sure it is relevant. And what about continuously upgradable distributions like a Debian/Unstable or a GenToo?